# Prolog check if list X has any duplicates

Tags: prolog

I have the function already but it is not working exactly as I want it to. The function I have is below..

```
isSet(List) :-
    \+ (
        select(Element, List, Tail),
        select(Element, Tail, _)
    ).
```

When I do isSet([1,2,3]) it gives me true which is expected. When I do isSet([1,1,2]) it gives me false which is also what I expect and is correct. My question is how can I pass a list that is already made? For example If I do X = [1,2,3] and than pass it as a argument like isSet(X) it should give me true but instead it generates an error.

What can I do to fix this?

Edit:

```
?- [db].
true.

?- X = [1,2,3].
X = [1, 2, 3].

?- isSet(X).
false.

?- X = (1,2,3).
X =  (1, 2, 3).

?- isSet(X).
false.

?- X = [1,1,2].
X = [1, 1, 2].

?- isSet(X).
false.
```

Comment: @GuyCoder can you elaborate sorry I am extremely new to this.

Comment: Of interest: [is_set/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/lists.pl?show=src#is_set/1)

Comment: They were just unfounded ideas that the more I thought about the more I realized they could have problems. The code for is_set/2 is what you need but is uses some advanced things, I.e. `'$skip_list'` for SWI-Prolog which I don't want to explain from the ground up.

Comment: What might work better for your needs is [list_to_set/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/lists.pl?show=src#list_to_set/2) which looks to use off the shelf predicates and should be understandable. If list_to_set/2 returns a set the same length as the input it should work. There might be a corner case I did not think of but then again I would create test cases to check it out. Do you require the list to be closed?

Comment: `?- X = [1,2,3].` is a _query_, it is _not_ a command to "set" a variable named `X`.

Answer (score 4):

SWI-Prolog allows the form `$Xs` to access a variable from a previous query. E.g.:

```
?- Xs=[1,2,3].
Xs = [1, 2, 3].

?- isSet($Xs).
Xs = [1, 2, 3].

?- isSet([1|$Xs]).
false.
```

BTW, it's slightly more efficient to write your code like this (and I suggest using `Rest` rather than `Tail`: the latter is typically used in the form `List=[Head|Tail]`):

```
isSet(List) :-
  \+ ( select(Element, List, Rest),
       member(Element, Rest)
     ).
```

Also, you can't write a list like this: `X = (1,2,3)` ... that's actually something different:

```
?- write_canonical((1,2,3)), nl.
','(1,','(2,3))
true.
```

Comment: I totally forgot about the '$' form. Thanks for jogging the memory.

Answer (score 3):

As there are discussions on how to best define the concept of "sets represented by lists", I humbly submit the following:

```
real_actual_set([]).
real_actual_set([X | Xs]) :-
    nonmember_of(X, Xs),
    real_actual_set(Xs).

nonmember_of(_X, []).
nonmember_of(X, [Y | Ys]) :-
    dif(X, Y),
    nonmember_of(X, Ys).
```

This is pure and works properly even in the presence of variables, including the most general query, and any lists containing variables that we would try to bind later:

```
?- real_actual_set([1, 2, 3]).
true .

?- real_actual_set([1, 1, 2]).
false.

?- real_actual_set([A, B, C]).
dif(A, C),
dif(A, B),
dif(B, C).

?- real_actual_set([A, A, B]).
false.

?- real_actual_set(Set).
Set = [] ;
Set = [_2222] ;
Set = [_2672, _2678],
dif(_2672, _2678) ;
Set = [_2970, _2976, _2982],
dif(_2970, _2982),
dif(_2970, _2976),
dif(_2976, _2982) ;
Set = [_3388, _3394, _3400, _3406],
dif(_3388, _3406),
dif(_3388, _3400),
dif(_3388, _3394),
dif(_3400, _3406),
dif(_3394, _3400),
dif(_3394, _3406) .

?- real_actual_set([A, B, C]), A = 1, B = 2, C = 3.
A = 1,
B = 2,
C = 3.

?- real_actual_set([A, B, C]), A = 1, B = 1, C = 3.
false.
```

This is quadratic, so it's "less performant" than other approaches. But as John Ousterhout is quoted, "The best performance improvement is the transition from the nonworking state to the working state."

Comment: Ah ok you did it already. I am almost certain that there are other answers on SO with this exact code in them but I can't be bothered to search now.

Comment: "correctness first, efficiency later!" (quoting myself) :)

Comment: @WillNess correctness has context. I will not make car analogies because they are stupid.

Comment: https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swipl/blob/master/library/ordsets.pl

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to check if a list is a set in Prolog is to sort it, removing duplicates, and check if its length is still the same. This is correct for all kinds of reasons, from very pragmatic (easy to program) to purely theoretic (it is the only robust approach to checking if a singly linked list is a set).

"But this is not what I asked" sure it isn't.

```
is_set(List) :-
    sort(List, Sorted),
    length(List, N),
    length(Sorted, N).
```

Don't throw Bloom filters and the like at me, at least not without proper justification.

To address the comments by @IsabelleNewbie, if you really want to use attributed variables to make sure that a list will forever remain a set under unification, you would do:

```
all_different([]).
all_different([H|T]) :-
    maplist(dif(H), T),
    all_different(T).
```

but this is a different thing altogether. You also shouldn't use it **unless** you want to take a list with variables and make sure no two elements in this list will ever unify. You get answers like this (in SWI-Prolog):

```
?- all_different(X).
X = [] ;
X = [_] ;
X = [_A, _B],
dif(_A, _B) ;
X = [_A, _B, _C],
dif(_A, _B),
dif(_A, _C),
dif(_B, _C) ;
X = [_A, _B, _C, _D],
dif(_A, _B),
dif(_A, _D),
dif(_A, _C),
dif(_B, _D),
dif(_B, _C),
dif(_C, _D) .
```

I suspect you can find this code in other places too.

Comment: As `sort/2` itself isn't robust in the presence of variables (`?- List = [A, B], sort(List, List), A = 2, B = 1.`), this cannot really be the "only robust approach". The *real* only robust approach is requiring that all members of the list be pairwise `dif/2`.

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie I was talking about making sure that a linked list is a set. As long as you have free variables in the list it shouldn't matter if you use select/3 or member/2 or sort.

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie by linked list I mean a sequence that only has a forward iterator; that is, no random access iterator or even a backward iterator. Prolog lists are _quite similar_ to singly linked lists. Either way, a Prolog list with more than one element and at least one free variable in it **cannot be** a set under unification either way, since the free variable unifies with any other term (including other variables).

Comment: ... unless there is a `dif` constraint preventing that unification.

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie yes certainly. So if this is the approach you want to take, you need to do something like: `all_different([]). all_different([H|T]) :- maplist(dif(H), T), all_different(T).` but this is again not checking if something is a set, it is doing something different.

Answer (score 1):

> For example If I do X = [1,2,3] and than pass it as a argument like isSet(X) it should give me true but instead it generates an error.

You should show us exactly what you tried!

This works:

```
?- Xs = [1, 2, 3], isSet(Xs).
Xs = [1, 2, 3].
```

Note that both parts (binding `Xs` and testing it) are in one query. Maybe you tried entering them separately:

```
?- Xs = [1, 2, 3].
Xs = [1, 2, 3].

?- isSet(Xs).
false.
```

This doesn't work because the value of `Xs` is not saved from one query to the next. This still isn't an error, though. However, it is not great behavior because failing for `isSet(Xs)` seems to imply that no sets exist at all.

Comment: Hi thank you for your comment. I edited my question to show the two different ways I tried doing this. Yes I need them to be separate (binding and testing) so instead of false it should be true. I agree it is undesirable behavior and I am trying to fix it.